Is there any textbook on prompt engineering suitable for teaching a college class?
I would like to know what resources come closest to providing an organized theoretical framework for the field of “prompt engineering”.


I would like to know what resources come closest to providing an organized theoretical framework for the field of “prompt engineering”.

I'd look into prompt design surveys, e.g.:

Navigate through Enigmatic Labyrinth A Survey of Chain of Thought Reasoning: Advances, Frontiers and Future (ACL 2024).
A Survey on In-context Learning
Pre-train, Prompt, and Predict: A Systematic Survey of Prompting Methods in Natural Language Processing (ACM Computing Surveys).

